# Get the closest not-future hour of day from GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I need to set my GregorianCalendar to a specific hour of day, which is the closest but not future. 
If the time now is 21:00, and I need set the hour 22, it will be set to yesterday. But if the time now is 23:00, it will be set for today.

Comment: check if the `getTime()` returns a value bigger or smaller than `new Date()`. if its bigger, you set the days -1 else you do nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
    LocalTime hour = LocalTime.of(22, 0);
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Indiana/Marengo"));
    ZonedDateTime closestHour = now.with(hour);
    if (closestHour.isAfter(now)) { // future
        closestHour = now.minusDays(1).with(hour);
    }

    System.out.println(closestHour);
```

This printed

```
2018-02-04T22:00-05:00[America/Indiana/Marengo]
```

The above is a sketch, not code that is ready for production. You need to supply your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be `America/Indiana/Marengo`. And the desired clock hour, of course. If the desired time doesn’t exist, typically in the spring transition to summer time ([DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)), [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) will pick a different time, you will need to detect that and act accordingly.

### java.time

You asked for a `GregorianCalendar`, and I will give you one, but allow me to mention that that class is long outdated and poorly designed, so you shouldn’t want one. I recommend you use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API instead.

If you need a [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) or just a [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object for a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now, convert like this:

```
    GregorianCalendar cal = GregorianCalendar.from(closestHour);
```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)